# PHP DOMDocument how to get that content of this tag?

Tags: php, html, parsing, domdocument

I am using domDocument hoping to parse this little html code.  I am looking for a specific `span` tag with a specific `id`.

```
<span id="CPHCenter_lblOperandName">Hello world</span>
```

My code:

```
$dom = new domDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html); // the @ is to silence errors and misconfigures of HTML
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('//span[@id="CPHCenter_lblOperandName"');

foreach($nodes as $node){
    echo $node->nodeValue;
}
```

But For some reason I think something is wrong with either the code or the html (how can I tell?):

- When I count nodes with `echo count($nodes);` the result is always 1
- I get nothing outputted in the nodes loop
- How can I learn the syntax of these complex queries?
- What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use simple getElementById:

```
$dom->getElementById('CPHCenter_lblOperandName')->nodeValue
```

or in selector way:

```
$selector = new DOMXPath($dom);

$list = $selector->query('/html/body//span[@id="CPHCenter_lblOperandName"]');

echo($list->item(0)->nodeValue);

//or 
foreach($list as $span) { 
    $text = $span->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: for the getElementById: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: So its returns null - are you sure you have CPHCenter_lblOperandName as id ? this is a working solution - i have tested it. try to print `$dom->getElementById('CPHCenter_lblOperandName')`

Comment: I fear my dom may not be valid, is there a way to tell?

Comment: yes - `loadHTML` returns bool for success [http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php)

Comment: and this is why you should not suppress errors when you write your code - so remove `@` or `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);`

Comment: ok some news here.... somehow all my document was truncated into `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title>
 &#1523;</title></head></html>`

Comment: the loadHTML returns true. Is there any reason why the HTML be truncated like this?

Comment: the html is loaded from a site. the site works on all browsers I tried

Comment: How do you take it ? something is truncating your data.

Comment: When I print it out simply, it shows everything... after the loadHTML, all gets messed up for some reason

Answer (score 3):

Your four part question gets an answer in three parts:

1. getElementsByTagName does not take an XPath expression, you need to give it a tag name;
2. Nothing is output because no tag would ever match the tagname you provided (see #1);
3. It looks like what you want is XPath, which means you need to create an XPath object - see [the PHP docs](http://php.net/DOMXPath) for more;

Also, a better method of controlling the libxml errors is to use libxml_use_internal_errors(true) (rather than the '@' operator, which will also hide other, more legitimate errors). That would leave you with code that looks something like this:

```
<?php    
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach($xpath->query("//span[@id='CPHCenter_lblOperandName']") as $node) {
    echo $node->textContent;
}
```

Comment: How can I extract the text inside that tag then? <span id="CPHCenter_lblOperandName">Hello world</span> ? [edited question]

Comment: Well, you can either use getElementsByTagName('span') and walk each node looking at its "id" to see if it's the node you wanted; or you can use XPath like I showed.

Comment: @TML: Or use `getElementById` ^_^

Comment: Hah - yes, or that (shame on me)

Comment: I still end up with an empty result. Is there a way to verify that the dom is ok? like printing it out somehow?

Comment: Sure - you can echo $dom->saveHTML(), for example. Or, if you're using a new enough PHP (late 5.3 series, early 5.4), you can see many properties of a DOM object with a var_dump().

Comment: ok some news here.... somehow all my document was truncated into `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title>
 &#1523;</title></head></html>`

Comment: as I used saveHTML(); but the html is valid... what may be causing this?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @TML, The other answer was a bit more elaborated, so I am sorry I can't mark you both as answered