# Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMDocument::getElementsById()

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm parsing a exterior html ([http://www.amazon.com/Toshiba-Satellite-C55-A5245-15-6-Inch-Horizon/dp/B00D78PZE8/ref=lp_9277875011_1_1?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1400886357&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00D78PZE8)) where I have a element like this:

`<span id="priceblock_ourprice" class="a-size-medium a-color-price">$429.99</span>`

and a php with the following code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;

libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
libxml_clear_errors();

$links = $dom->getElementsById('priceblock_ourprice');

foreach ($links as $link ) {
    echo "- ".$link->nodeValue."<br>";
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMDocument::getElementsById()
```

Anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't it getElementById?

Comment: You are right! jajajaj sorry, although now I'm getting:

    Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Any idea what could be?

Comment: But then, I should change the html tag to a class? because I can't change it.

Should I delete the foreach and just do the echo?

Comment: You can't change the HTML and it includes multiple elements with the same id?

Comment: possible duplicate of [php domdocument read element inner text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054815/php-domdocument-read-element-inner-text)

Comment: @showdev sadly I can't change the html. I doing what the post says, but still gives me "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: This might be helpful: [PHP DOMDocument how to get that content of this tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16093402/php-domdocument-how-to-get-that-content-of-this-tag)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsById()` is not a method of `DOMDocument`, you should try `getElementById()` instead. I don't even think two elements can have the same id, so you won't be able to get a collection (array) based on id.

Comment: For reference:
[DOMDocument::getElementById](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php) And yus, the ElementId **MUST** be unique. Otherwise the document will be invalid.

Comment: You are right! thanks, now I do a unique echo, although now I'm getting: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object  and I'm not receiving any value :P

Comment: @showdev changing to innerHTML shows the same, any other idea?

Comment: @Trifit Sorry, I failed to notice that you are using DOMDocument. I was thinking javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I don't quite understand this, seems that Firebug in Firefox was showing me the wrong ID, I used the following code to get the Id of the different spans and the right one was:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();

libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
libxml_clear_errors();

$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('span');

foreach($nodes as $node) {
echo $node->getAttribute('id'). '->'.$node->textContent.'<br>';
}
```

and it returned a different id for the field that I was looking for, I guess I had some error at some point, really sorry for waisting your time.